# Regex that deletes everything except for any tags that contains an specific string inside of it

Tags: regex, bash, vim, awk

I need a regex that can be applied on vim editor, or bash (grep command), that will delete everything in a file, leaving only the tags containing an specific string:

```
<generic>
stuff1
stuff2
stuff3
</generic>
```

and

```
<generic>
stuff1
stuff2
DESIRED_STRING
stuff3
</generic>
```

The first one would be wiped and the second one would remain because of the `DESIRED_STRING`.

At the end, I need a file with tons of tags that contains a modifier on it. This process will be executed several times to separate one huge file into multiple others.

This `(?<=\<custom_item\>).*?(?=\<\/custom_item\>)` got me in a point where I could match the content inside of the tags. Not able to filter it though.

The file will always follow this structure

```
<tag>
system      : "Linux"
type        : CHECK
</tag>
```

Where 'CHECK' is the modifier and the word I am looking for

Thank you!!

Comment: Use XML processing tools for XML data.

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a pattern matching/search/query mechanism. It cannot mutate anything. Think of regexes as what google is for internet pages - but for strings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus  This  -> (?<=\<custom_item\>).*?(?=\<\/custom_item\>) got me in a point where I could match the content inside of the tags. Not able to filter it though. Sorry for not including that on the question, doing it now.

Comment: @Andersnk I would like to use the regular expression as the pattern for vim to actually delete.

Comment: Is your input always separated by lines? Can you have your DESIRED_STRING inline, e.g. `stuff2 DESIRED_STRING stuff3` on the same line?

Comment: @vdavid I edited the question to show the structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this approach using `awk`:

```
awk '/<generic>/ { tag=1 }
     tag && /DESIRED_STRING/ { p=1 }
     tag { s = s $0 RS }
     /<\/generic>/ { if (p) printf "%s", s; tag=p=0; s="" }' file
```

We use 2 flags to track our state here. `tag` represents state when we are inside open and close tags and `p` represents a state when we find our desired string while inside the open/close tags.

Comment: Honestly, thank you @anubhava , you just saved me a lot a time and work!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative, in Vim: it is much easier to match than avoid to match, so....

```
Gmz:1,'z g/DESIRED_STRING/norm yat:$pu<Ctrl-V><Enter><Enter>'zdgg
```

where `<Ctrl-V>` and `<Enter>` are supposed to be keys, not actual text to be entered.

`Gmz` will set a `z` mark at the last line. Then, we search for the `DESIRED_STRING`, and at each one, yank the tag, then paste it to the bottom of the file (in order). Then `'zdgg` to delete the original (from the mark `z` to the top of the file).

Basically, instead of trying to delete everything and making exceptions for the desired content, pull the desired content out first, then delete everything.

Bonus: This will work even with tags that don't align with line breaks (even though OP doesn't have those). For example,

```
outside<tag>inside
foo DESIRED_STRING inside</tag>outside
```

will correctly produce

```
<tag>inside
foo DESIRED_STRING inside</tag>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amadam, I actually think I'm gonna face that problem, it will help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With Vim regex:

```
:%s/<\([^>]*\)>\(\_.\(DESIRED_STRING\)\@!\)\{-}<\/\1>//
```

This regex uses a negative look ahead, `\@!`, to match all blocks of text not containing `DESIRED_STRING`. These blocks are then removed with the `:%s` command